# Cell value will not compare to a Variant array value

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue getting array values to compare to values stored in cells on the spreadsheet.

I have tried having the cell value compare directly to the array value, but the check fails every time.

To attempt to correct this issue I have tried assigning the cell value on each iteration to a variable dimmed as varient (Just as the array is dimmed a varient)

Values are added to the array successfully and the varient type is used as some invoices are numbers only while others include letters.

When I walk through my code the variable is not being assigned/accepting a value. Every time the comparison statement is reached the variable shows that it is empty.

```
Dim Paidlrow As Long
Dim lrow As Long

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Consolid As Worksheet
Dim PaidInv As Worksheet
Dim Summary As Worksheet

Dim Invoices() As Variant
Dim InvCheck As Variant
Dim txt As String
Dim Formula As String

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim Cleared As Long
Dim LInv As Long
Dim NewBlank As Long

Dim MaxSheets As Integer

Set wb = Workbooks("Wire Payments projections for Euro's")
Set Consolid = wb.Sheets("Consolidation")
Set Summary = wb.Sheets("Pay Summary")
Set PaidInv = wb.Sheets("Paid Invoices")

'define define and define

MaxSheets = wb.Sheets.Count
lrow = Consolid.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Cleared = 1

ReDim Preserve Invoices(1 To Cleared)

i = 2
With wb

    'begin inv extraction loop
    For i = 2 To lrow
        ReDim Preserve Invoices(1 To Cleared)

        'if inv is marked for payment, add to array and move details to paid inv tab
        With PaidInv
            Paidlrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End With

        With Consolid
            If .Cells(i, 10) = "X" Or .Cells(i, 10) = "x" Then
                Invoices(Cleared) = .Cells(i, 1)
                Consolid.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=PaidInv.Cells(Paidlrow, 1)
                Consolid.Rows(i).Clear
                Cleared = Cleared + 1
            End If
        End With

    Next i
End With
    'loop through each sheet to remove paid invoices identifie in previous loop
    For k = 1 To MaxSheets
        If wb.Sheets(k).Name <> Summary.Name And wb.Sheets(k).Name <> PaidInv.Name And wb.Sheets(k).Name <> Consolid.Name Then
            With wb.Sheets(k)
                LInv = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                For j = LBound(Invoices) To UBound(Invoices)
                    For l = 7 To LInv
                        InvCheck = .Cells(l, 2).Value

                        If Invoices(j) = InvCheck And InvCheck <> "" Then

                            '.Rows(l).Delete

                            NewBlank = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            .Range("A7:K7").Copy
                            .Range(.Cells(NewBlank, 1), .Cells(NewBlank, 11)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

                            '.Cells(NewBlank, 1) = Right(.Cells(1, 9), 6)

                            'Formula = "=$B$3*I"
                            'Formula = Formula & NewBlank
                            '.Cells(NewBlank, 10).Formula = Formula



                        End If
                    Next l
                Next j
            End With
        End If
    Next k
```

I have commented out code for the ease of testing. With the way it is now it should format some additional cells to match the formatting above it.

**UPDATE**

For kicks and giggles, I changed the Array and associated variable check to String type rather than variant. For some reason, this fixed the issue I was having. I am so confused...

Comment: on which line are you having the error? Where does it show the variable being empty?

Comment: the line "InvCheck = .cells(l,2).value" is not passing a value to the variable InvCheck. As a result, the check " If Invoices(j) = InvCheck And InvCheck <> "" Then" always returns a false value.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a dot missing:

```
With wb.Sheets(k)
    LInv = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

should be:

```
With wb.Sheets(k)
    LInv = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

to ensure that `LInv` is read from sheet number k.

As it is, the code is equivalent to:

```
With wb.Sheets(k)
    LInv = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

and, if the active sheet doesn't have any values in the cells you are looking at, the comparison will fail.

There's a similar issue with this line later on in the code:

```
NewBlank = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

should be:

```
NewBlank = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel dumb for not catching that simple mistake. That fixed an issue for which ranges the cells were looking at, but not the issue of no value being passed to the variable.